# ERD Relations in Visio

Tags: visio, erd, entity-relationship

I am making an ERD in visio, but not getting "Dynamic Many-To-Many"/"Dynamic One-To-Many" arrow to join my entities.
Can anybody know, from where in visio i can get it?
I am getting straight linked arrow, but i need the dynamic one which is flexible to move anywhere not in just horizontal/vertical way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I little experience with Visio for data modeling and what little I have indicates that there are better tools out there. I would recommend you consider one of the following:

- Erwin
- Rational Software Architect
- ERStudio

If price is a consideration, oracle has a pretty well rounded tool (SQL Developer Data Modeler)

Hope this helps.